# Does my SELECT produce anything?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is there anything wrong with my `SELECT`? It is supposed to calculate the number of distinct IPs on each day and then calculate the sum. Here is the query:

```
SELECT SUM(NumIpsPerDay) AS user_hits
FROM
  (SELECT DATE(tracking.timestamp) AS DayTrackCount,
          COUNT(DISTINCT tracking.ip) AS NumIpsPerDay
   FROM USER,
        tracking
   GROUP BY DATE(tracking.timestamp)
   WHERE tracking.user_id = $user_id
   GROUP BY $user_id LIMIT 1)
```

I was looking at it and I figured it might be the date.

Is there anything wrong with my `SELECT`?

Comment: Why would you think something is wrong? What isn't working? What results do you get? What are you expecting?

Comment: You might want to edit your question - does your select produce anything? If so, what does it do that it shouldn't?

Comment: I checked the NumIpsPerDay and I do not get anything showing... so I am not so sure is working right

Comment: Where should be used before group by

Comment: *Is* there something wrong with the select? And, if so, what?

Comment: Still with the WHERE it does not produce anything as NumIpsPerDay

Comment: Does the code after the first FROM work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(NumIpsPerDay) AS user_hits 
FROM 
(
    SELECT DATE(tracking.timestamp) AS DayTrackCount, 
           COUNT(DISTINCT tracking.ip) AS NumIpsPerDay 
    FROM user, tracking 
    WHERE tracking.user_id = $user_id 
    GROUP BY DATE(tracking.timestamp) 
) x
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(tab.NumIpsPerDay) AS user_hits
FROM
   (SELECT DATE(tracking.timestamp) AS DayTrackCount,
   COUNT(DISTINCT tracking.ip) AS NumIpsPerDay
   FROM USER, tracking
   WHERE tracking.user_id = $user_id
   GROUP BY DATE(tracking.timestamp)) as tab
```

Why do you want to put in subquery date(tracking.timestamp) ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes.  You are doing a `cross join` (cartesian product) between `user` and `tracking`.  And yet, you are not using any fields from the `user` table.  You probably don't need the table at all.

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(NumIpsPerDay) AS user_hits
FROM (SELECT DATE(tracking.timestamp) AS DayTrackCount,
             COUNT(DISTINCT tracking.ip) AS NumIpsPerDay
      FROM tracking
      WHERE tracking.user_id = $user_id
      GROUP BY DATE(tracking.timestamp
     ) t
GROUP BY $user_id;
```

In addition:

1. The subquery did not have an alias
2. The `limit` is not needed
3. The `where` clause came after the `group by`